# What's a simple way to test a connection timeout?

Tags: networking, powershell

I've recently increased the timeouts on all our LBs so they're consistant and I want to test that the new timeout has actually applied. Is there a simple powershell snippet or web tool which will simply keep a connection open until it times out therefore testing the timeout?

I'm thinking of something along the lines of a slow loris attack would do the trick.

Comment: asking for products, software and services are off-topic, please describe your business related question or issue please

Comment: @djdomi The first part of the question covers that "I've recently increased the timeouts on all our LBs so they're consistent and I want to test that the new timeout has actually applied. "